# How to Properly Change an InventoryID of a Serial Record

Tags: acumatica

Does anyone know if there is a simple/correct way to change the inventory id of an existing serial item within Acumatica? We had serial records created in the system under the wrong inventory id, and we need to re-associate these serial records to their correct inventory id. We prefer not to create new serial records to solve this need for a variety of reasons that pertain to preserving the history and other custom fields attached to this serial item/record.

Answer (score 0):

The best option, in my opinion, is to perform negative inventory adjustments to get them removed from the incorrect InventoryID and then positive adjustments to get them attached to the correct InventoryID.  You should be able to do 2 import scenarios to the Inventory Adjustments screen to create these pretty quickly.  There are accounting reasons to do it this way.  If you try to update the database tables directly on the backend - you can possibly end up with a mess on your hands.